# SQL: How to get my count specific?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I am lost in my joins once again.

My count should be 4 instead of 16. 
Can someone help me out? I can't find my problem on my own.

```
    SELECT  COUNT(TRK.REACTIE_ID) AS AANTAL_REACTIES,
            AVG(W.WAARDERING) AS AANTAL_STERREN,
            S.UITGEVER,
            S.NAAM AS TVSHOW_NAAM,
            S.BESCHRIJVING,
            S.AFBEELDING_BESTANDSPAD,
            S.ONDERTITEL,
            S.WEBSITE,
            C.NAAM AS CATEGORIE,
            A.AFBEELDING_BESTANDSPAD,
            A.VIDEO_BESTANDSPAD,
            A.AFLEVERINGNR AS AFLEVERING,
            A.SEIZOENNR AS SEIZOEN,
            A.NAAM AS AFLEVERING_NAAM,
            A.DUUR AS MINUTEN
FROM  CATEGORIEEN_KOPPELTABEL CK 
      JOIN CATEGORIE C ON C.CATEGORIE_ID = CK.CATEGORIE_ID 
         JOIN TV_SHOW S ON S.TV_SHOW_ID = CK.TV_SHOW_ID AND S.NAAM = 'South Park' 
          LEFT JOIN TVSHOW_REACTIES_KOPPELTABEL TRK ON TRK.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID
                 LEFT JOIN WAARDERING_TVSHOW W ON W.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID
                            JOIN AFLEVERING A ON A.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID 
                             WHERE a.airdate = (SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(AIRDATE, 'DD:MM:YYYY')) 
                                                FROM AFLEVERING)                        
GROUP BY    TRK.TV_SHOW_ID,
            S.UITGEVER,
            S.NAAM,
            S.BESCHRIJVING,
            S.AFBEELDING_BESTANDSPAD,
            S.ONDERTITEL,S.WEBSITE, 
            C.NAAM,
            A.AFBEELDING_BESTANDSPAD,
            A.VIDEO_BESTANDSPAD,
            A.AFLEVERINGNR,
            A.SEIZOENNR,
            A.NAAM,
            A.DUUR,
            W.TV_SHOW_ID;
```

[RESULT OF THE QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpQMZ.jpg)
That is my result at the moment but there are 4 records of reactie.

Comment: No one could say what is wrong without example of data. You can prepare example on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @Dmitry I added link to my result! :)

Comment: Oh my god, no! :))))) Example on sqlfiddle.com. Look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd950/1/0

Comment: @Dmitry is right. What would you do if you were asked to correct a query if you couldn't see the data at all? Read how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "My count should be 4 instead of 16."

This indicates a missing JOIN condition or WHERE filter.  This sort of thing can only be diagnosed by comparing the raw i.e. input data with the output and seeing which values appear too often.  If you can't see this immediately, remove the aggregation and the group by clause, and perhaps add in some primary key columns.

One clue is that the aggregations are applied to values from the tables with outer joins:

```
LEFT JOIN TVSHOW_REACTIES_KOPPELTABEL TRK ON TRK.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID
LEFT JOIN WAARDERING_TVSHOW W ON W.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID
```

Outer joins can suck in rows we're not expecting, so you should check the logic you're trying to implement.

One other thing: don't mix filter conditions in the JOIN clause.  The whole point of the ANSI 92 syntax is to keep them separate.  So this ought to be in the WHERE clause:

```
AND S.NAAM = 'South Park'
```

It probably won't affect the actual result but occasionally it might.